# Xamarin.Forms - Get miles Between Two Coordinates Using Xamarin.Essentials

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gps, xamarin.essentials

I am trying to get the miles between to locations using xamarin essentials.  I a have the coordinates for the staring point and destination.  The Distance variable equals to 2134.13057845059.  Do I need to convert this number to miles?  It should equal to 30 miles or so.

```
 var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            var courtLocation = new Location(Convert.ToDouble(item.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(item.Longitude));

            double distance = Location.CalculateDistance(location, courtLocation, DistanceUnits.Miles);
```

Answer (score 0):

the last parameter of `CalculateDistance` is the unit for the return type.

you are requesting km

```
double distance = Location.CalculateDistance(location, courtLocation, DistanceUnits.Kilometers);
```

if you want to request miles, use

```
double distance = Location.CalculateDistance(location, courtLocation, DistanceUnits.Miles);
```

this works for me, if you are still getting a bad result I would double check your inputs and conversions

```
var loc1 = new Location(33.887749, -84.345818);
var loc2 = new Location(33.807920, -84.046791);

// result is 18.023...
double distance = Location.CalculateDistance(loc1, loc2, DistanceUnits.Miles);
```

Comment: I set it to mails, and still get a large number and I know these coordinates and between 30 and 40 Miles away from each other.

Comment: what are the two locations you are using?

Comment: destination - lat:33.887749 Long:-84.345818

CurrentLocation - lat:33.807920  long:-84.046791

Comment: Thanks, how would you add drive time to the distance value?

Comment: `time = distance/speed`.  Or if you want a "real" value you would need to use some service that provides route data

Comment: This is most likely an "as the crow flies" calculation drawing a straight line from the to points using the Haversine formula. It's not going to match the driving distance most of the time. There are many paid products/services that exist to give you the actual driving distance between two points. Google, Bing, PCMiler for truck routing, etc.